# Const reference to a casted int from unsigned int

Tags: c++, reference, constants, const-reference

I am having some trouble understanding the behaviour in this snippet:

```
unsigned int i = 2;
const int &r = i;
std::cout << r << "\n";
i = 100;
std::cout << r << "\n";
```

The first print statement gives 2 as I expect, but when I change the value of the referenced variable, it is not reflected in the reference. The second print statement also gives 2, but I think it should give 100?

If I make variable `i` into type `int` instead of `unsigned int`, it works as I expect. What is going on here?

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/22f9e5b36c480039)

Comment: Shouldn't the reference be `const unsigned int &r = i;`?

Comment: Yes, I think it should be that, but I want to know why this particular snippet behaves this way.

Comment: ...is it undefined? I cannot find if that is true, the other answers make it seem like it is defined behaviour too.

Comment: No, it's not UB. The answers explain pretty well what's actually happening.

Comment: This is one reason why `auto &` is a thing.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can only have a reference to an object of the same type.

You cannot have an `int` reference to an `unsigned int`.

What is happening here is, essentially:

```
const int &r = (int)i;
```

A new `int` temporary gets constructed, a new temporary object, and a `const` reference is bound to it.

Using your debugger, you should be able to observe the fact that the reference is referring to a completely different object:

```
(gdb) n
6   const int &r = i;
(gdb) 
7   std::cout << r << "\n";
(gdb) p i
$1 = 2
(gdb) p &i
$2 = (unsigned int *) 0x7fffffffea0c
(gdb) p &r
$3 = (const int *) 0x7fffffffe9fc
(gdb) q
```

Answer (score 9):

> The second print statement also gives 2, but I think it should give 100?

Because a temporary `int` is created here.

For `const int &r = i;`, `i` (`unsigned int`) needs to be converted to `int` at first, means a temporary `int` will be created and then be bound to `r` (temporary could be bound to lvalue reference to const), it has nothing to do with the original variable `i` any more.

> If I make variable i into type int instead of unsigned int, it works as I expect.

Because no conversion and temporary is needed, `i` could be bound to `r` directly.